Access internal website connected to a Wifi through ethernet
I have an wired ethernet network in the 10.0.101.x range. I connected one wifi router to this wired network. Any device that connects to the wifi router has a 192.168.x.x IP address.
I have one NUC that runs an intranet website using Apache server. This NUC is connected to the wifi and cannot be connected via ethernet.
What I want to do is access the website running on the NUC using a desktop connected only to the wired ethernet. How can I do this? Any help is much appreciated.

Your WiFi router is using NAT (Network Address Translation) protocol to allow devices on your 192.168.x.x network to access devices on your 10.0.101.x network and, assuming you have a route set up from there, to the Internet. Any connection from a 192.168.x.x devices appears on the 10.0.101.x network as coming from the IP address of the router. (Individual IP/TCP port numbers are mapped to connections from the 192.168.x.x devices.)
A side effect of NAT is that without special setup, a device on the 10.0.101.x network cannot initiate a connection to a 192.168.x.x device. It has no way to address such a device.
To get around this, your WiFi router can be configured to do port mapping. For example, assume that you want outside access to the web server (TCP port 80) on 192.168.0.5. You would configure the router to provide a port number to the outside world that gets mapped to 192.168.0.5:80. Assuming that the router's outside address is 10.0.101.66, you could select port 5000 to map. Therefore, any packets directed to 10.0.101.66:5000 would be mapped by the router to 192.168.0.5:80. You could then point a browser to http://10.0.101.66:5000. If the router itself doesn't present a web server to its outside network, you could map port 80 to port 80 and not have to add the :5000. Note that each port number of the router's outside network interface can only map to one port on one internal address.
Configuring port mapping is dependent on your specific router.

It sounds like you're doing double NAT, which is not recommended unless you really know what you're doing and have a good justification for it.
Thus the usual recommended solution is to make your downstream Wi-Fi router act as a simple AP, not a NAT gateway. Some wireless routers give you a way to configure AP mode instead of NAT mode, but some don't. If yours doesn't, then just turn off its built-in DHCP server feature (or give it a zero-length pool of IP addresses to lease out), and move the Ethernet cable that's currently in its WAN port and put it in one of its LAN ports. This will make your whole network one flat subnet with a single DHCP server, so your wireless clients will be on the same 10.0.101.0/24 subnet with all your wired devices.
